# How to manually map collection using laravel/php and get total amount

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I currently have the below json response that the API is returning. I am able to return it using Laravel Eloquent. There are several users and each user has a several receipts. A receipt has types and status. I want to try to get the total sum amount for each receipt that is related to its type and status. I was able to return the below json response using

`$this->user->with('receipts')->has('receipts')->get(['id', 'name']);`

I have tried using multiple laravel collections methods https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods But I am still unable to get the desired response.

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "kent",
    "receipts": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "user_id": 1,
        "type_id": 1,
        "status": 0,
        "amount": 100
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "user_id": 1,
        "type_id": 1,
        "status": 0,
        "amount": 100
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "user_id": 1,
        "type_id": 2,
        "status": 1,
        "amount": 50
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "user_id": 1,
        "type_id": 2,
        "status": 0,
        "amount": 30
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "user_id": 1,
        "type_id": 2,
        "status": 0,
        "amount": 30
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "user_id": 1,
        "type_id": 1,
        "status": 0,
        "amount": 20
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "user_id": 1,
        "type_id": 1,
        "status": 1,
        "amount": 10
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "allison",
    "receipts": [
      {
        "id": 9,
        "user_id": 2,
        "type_id": 1,
        "status": 0,
        "amount": 20
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I expect to get this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "kent",
    "receipts": [
      {
        "performance and deleted": 220,
        "performance and not deleted": 10,
        "project and deleted": 60,
        "project and deleted": 50
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "allison",
    "receipts": [
      {
        "performance and deleted": 20,
        "performance and not deleted": 0,
        "project and deleted": 0,
        "project and not deleted": 0
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My main concern is to use laravel collection methods and easy to read code to get my expected result

Comment: Please provide the databse structure with some data.

Comment: I would suggest to user Raw Query instead of writing complicated Eloquent Method, Where you are eventually going to user Raw anyway!

Comment: the db data is what I have on top above the "expected" answer

Comment: @VishalTarkar How am I able to  get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this way, I believe you get your expected result with nice readable code.

I'll assume that you have `$users` variable which contains a list of users in collection (And probably the receipts are already loaded).

```
// You need to name the keys as you desire. (I can't figure out the labels by the type_id and status numbers).
$statusPair = collect([
    'performance and deleted' => [
        'type_id' => 1,
        'status'  => 0,
    ],
    'something'               => [
        'type_id' => 1,
        'status'  => 1,
    ],
    'something 2'             => [
        'type_id' => 2,
        'status'  => 0,
    ],
    'something 3'             => [
        'type_id' => 2,
        'status'  => 1,
    ],
]);

$data = $users->map(function ($user) use ($statusPair) {
    $receipts = $user->receipts;

    $sums = $statusPair->mapWithKeys(function ($pair, $statusLabel) use ($receipts) {
        $filtered = $receipts;
        foreach ($pair as $key => $value) {
            $filtered = $filtered->where($key, $value);
        }
        $sum = $filtered->sum('amount');

        return [
            $statusLabel => $sum,
        ];
    });

    return [
        'id'       => $user->id,
        'name'     => $user->name,
        'receipts' => $sums->toArray(),
    ];
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Can the `foreach` be replaced with the `each` method?
What is the $pair and $statusLabel?

Comment: `foreach` can be `each`, those are basically the same thing. Your requirement wasn't really clear for the receipts labels (like `performance and deleted` or `performance and not deleted`, and this is what `$statusLabel` is in my code), so I assumed they are determined by the pair of type_id and status. If it's not something you want, you can modify the pairs.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help

```
$user->receipts->sum('amount');
```